# MIME type not valid when uploading image using REST API

Tags: magento2, api, product-images, image-upload

I'm trying to set a product image using the web api by POSTing to this url:

```
http://my_magento_server/rest/V1/products/my-url-key/media
```

With the following content:

```
{"entry":
  {
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "Image",
    "position": 1,
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",
    "content": {
      "base64EncodedData": "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",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "new image"
    }
  }
}
```

But I get 400 response:

```
The image MIME type is not valid or not supported
```

Any idea how I can upload a file as product image in Magento 2?

Comment: image/jpeg should be image/jpg

Comment: @Arunendra still getting the same error

Comment: Hello Michael
You found solution ? If you have solution please share me.
I am image upload via rest api i geting ''message": "Provided image name contains forbidden characters." error.

Answer (score 4):

After base64 decoding the image you provided, I noticed it is the PNG image, not JPEG.

Try changing the "type" attribute in your JSON to "image/png".

Additionally, you should add file extension to your "name" attribute.

The example below worked fine for me.

```
{
        "entry": {
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "Image",
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"
            ],
            "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.png",
            "content": {
                "base64EncodedData": "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",
                "type": "image/png",
                "name": "new_image.png"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: file , "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.png" does not seems relevant since magento creates this path automatically. I wonder if it can be used to replace an existing previously posted image.

Answer (score 1):

This a Megento Bug still unresolved. I fixed this one by wrapping this condition
in MAGE_ROOT_FOLDER/vendor/magento/framework/Api/ImageContentValidator.php

```
if ($sourceMimeType != $imageContent->getType() || !$this->isMimeTypeValid($sourceMimeType)) {
            throw new InputException(new Phrase('The image MIME type is not valid or not supported.'));
        }
```

inside another condition like this

```
if ($sourceMimeType != 'image/png') {
        if ($sourceMimeType != $imageContent->getType() || !$this->isMimeTypeValid($sourceMimeType)) {
            throw new InputException(new Phrase('The image MIME type is not valid or not supported.'));
        }
    }
```

I know that modifying any of the files in vendor folder is a bad idea but while this issue remains unfixed there is something you should do to get the job done!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that its image/jpg which causes this problem.
I simply replace the type as image/jpeg when the extension is jpg and it works like a charm.

//Getting path info
$contentType    = pathinfo($saved_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($contentType == 'jpg') $contentType="jpeg";

$content_Type   = 'image/'.$contentType;

Answer (score 0):

I think the name must contain the filename extension. 
Try it with `"name": "new image.jpg"` or `"name": "new image.png"`

I also have a problem, I can't upload my images as thumbnails. I must set this manually.

```
{
  "entry": {
    "mediaType": "image",
    "disabled": "false",
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "content": {
      "base64EncodedData": "...", 
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "image.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did one thing wrong.You don't need to use `"file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg",`
in your request packet. It is generated by Magento itself.Final packet should be look like this..

```
{
    "entry": {
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Image",
        "position": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "types": [
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ],

        "content": {
            "base64EncodedData": "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",
            "type": "image/png",
            "name": "new_image.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Try it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on a perfectly fine image: I had `"type": "image/jpeg"` and the content was indeed JPEG. The problem was that I had a dot in the image name: `IMG1234.56`. Magento interprets it as a file extension and thus return this error. The fix was to change that dot to another character, like `_`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that magento checks the content->type value, and only accepts jpeg and not jpg. so even if your image is a .jpg, you need to build this data value as 'image/jpeg'..