# Sign Up with Customer Image attribute REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I added image attribute in customer create account, edit account in `Setup/InstallData.php` as following:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Avatar",
            "input"    => "image",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $promotion_code   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar");

        $promotion_code = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'avatar');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $promotion_code->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);

        $promotion_code->save();



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
```

The problem is I cant do sign up via REST API, I am using this API :

**POST** `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers`

**Body** :

```
  {
     "customer": {
         "email": "abc@gmail.com",
         "firstname": "Abc",
         "lastname": "Xyz" ,
         "custom_attributes": [
          {
            "attribute_code": "avatar",
            "value": ""  //encoded base_64 image
          }
        ]

     },

     "password": "Abc@123456"
  }
```

I tries to put Image in encoding base64 image, but I always get this error:

```
{
    "message": "The image content must be valid base64 encoded data."
}
```

How can I solve this?

In general are the body parameters correct, If not how can I post correct body?

Comment: Can you try this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109274/mime-type-not-valid-when-uploading-image-using-rest-api

Comment: Thank you, but I think this related to product API, and here in my case committed to customer sign up API.

Comment: Did you use online tools to check the base64 format?

Comment: Yes, and can encode and decode successfully. Kindly,  could you try my code and test the body parameters ?  and for full code, I asked this question before  with full code https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2/186384#186384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below json format, it worked for me:-

@PY Yick suggestion provided the hint:-

```
{
 "customer": {
     "email": "abc1@gmail.com",
     "firstname": "Abc",
     "lastname": "Xyz" ,
     "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "twilio_image",
        "value": {
            "base64EncodedData": "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",
            "type": "image/png",
            "name": "new_image.png"
        }
      }
    ]

 },

 "password": "Abc@123456"
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, How can I encode image? if you are using specific tool, provide me it is working only for your image and when encode any image I got error ''"message": "The image MIME type is not valid or not supported." ,  Another question Is this solution working for edit customer ? sorry for the more questions.

Comment: @base64_encode(file_get_contents('new_image.png')) use this you can check in framework\Api\ImageContentValidatorTest.php at line 114, magento is using the same and it worked for me as well.

Comment: Ok, It is working fine. what about edit customer?  Thanks..

Comment: means, you want to add image for customer as well

Comment: I mean it is working fine when sign up, I am asking How can I edit customer with image attribute?