# Error on image upload with REST api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, unserialize

Referring to [MIME type not valid when uploading image using REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109274/mime-type-not-valid-when-uploading-image-using-rest-api)

I am trying to upload image for a product through `REST api`.

**Request Code:**

**API:** http://192.168.0.133/index.php/rest/V1/products/ABC_123456/media

**METHOD:** POST

**BODY:**

```
{
 "entry": {
 "media_type": "image",
 "label": "Image",
 "disabled": false,
    "types": [
        "image",
        "small_image",
        "thumbnail"
    ],
 "file": "string",
 "content": {
   "base64_encoded_data": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQcAAAGGCAYAAAB2R0TaAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAgAElEQVR4nO2dd3hUxdfHv3fTKAmhiwhIEwFBbIAiSlGKiIoovoqoWEDABFAQseNPBV70lZJIVZqCCvwQRQVBukgTEKQovZdQEgglCdk97x+TwGbZcsvMnbub+TzPeZTs3pkzc+eenTtz5hxAoVAoFAqFQi+abAUU3EkE0AhAzTwpDaB43mcXAWQBOADgHwB/A9gFwGO/mgqFQjQagLsBDAOwFexBJwNyFMA4AA8AcNmsu0KhEEA8gP5gMwAjxiCY/A2gE5SRUCjCkhgwo3AC/IyCr/h+mlMRAh4JWmWH9/4CzEnHmxW4su1lN2fAXHXt5DcAx22u05scXPGN8EamkZ4K8XFGIxoexmE65N2EXPjPdUgwH8jVKt/C/lRnuTCf85IH34K5ufvyI8RmJwsEQUWXdgxLIeedMlgE4WqQE//1PGeZa5BvRTxsEgxaHf6SUb9gVqrQv9rzwesACu4YyR5La8/UuCYSSCmIzzLJMN6KeMgwn0Jre1O5y83m2+ZTbrJYLy0BdCTpR/SSCMGGkZ51n+V6duRmS5rS1wOPWgL+uy3VGVWuvQiQA8Z7NeopiA0G0V5V8SjHk69DoCOedZzC5eB5MvbG1BGPApgneYrKzIoWYPGwDESNKNN+UQelvzfgl63YLQ4etlGeiiYFnDeRoH0btxYUcsWKw/f511GkB1SXpdB+BgAL3SwM5jRBItwdZ2nPaL1j+ATgR2FkMmz4BfHNKjYGePFD4kgCVX9f71Wg+gtkylwGJQ5Kf1I7DzCD+B+WlEIs3Bzojkv+pdBPAxWJAYmXRBQbfq4wD6wRlbyM+AvdpYMQx7Adxlt+JmEOmBqIfSYMlw/KVvl0URABXAfPfPSdbFDqLBMlKdBNu+dArlwWaaR8B+sZ2CCyyalRljlQ3gMF91xPH/Y6G7EHnoGcUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
    ",

  "type": "image/png",
  "name": "new_image2.png"
   }
  }
}
```

**RESPONSE:**

> "message": "Decoding error: \nUnable to unserialize value.\n#0 /var/www/magento221/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer/Json.php(64): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('{\n  \"entry\": {\n...')\n#1 /var/www/magento221/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(141): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Json->deserialize('{\n  \"entry\": {\n...')\n#2 /var/www/magento221/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/Interceptor.php(37):

What could be the issue?

Using `magento verion 2.2.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In base64_encoded_data pass only **Base64 Encoded Data** of image.

**Below is the correct body request.**

```
{
 "entry": {
 "media_type": "image",
 "label": "Image",
 "disabled": false,
    "types": [
        "image",
        "small_image",
        "thumbnail"
    ],
 "file": "string",
 "content": {
 "base64_encoded_data": "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",
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "name": "new_image2.jpeg"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay i have updated my answer with my image data and its parameters check it

Comment: yes working...it's possible to send multiple image in same format ?

Comment: Well magento is not allowing multiple image upload using rest api , you need to do that operation with for loop and regarding format yes that is fine

Comment: Really thanks for info,Can you give me any ref site so that I encode image to base64 correctly for jpg/png?

Comment: @Hiranya - Yes sure - here is the link - https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64